# Don't process child nodes (Using "SelectNodes")

Tags: xml, vb.net, parent-node

Example XML;

```
<root>
  <cmdset>Set 1
    <cmd>Command 1</cmd>
  </cmdset>
  <cmdset>Set 2
    <cmd>Command 2</cmd>
  </cmdset>
</root>
```

I only want to pull the text from within the `<cmdset>` tags. Example code;

```
Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load("help.xml")
        For Each Element As XmlElement In doc.SelectNodes("//cmdset")
            Console.WriteLine(Element.InnerText)
        Next
        Console.Read()
    End Sub
```

Current output;

```
Set 1
    Command 1
Set 2
    Command 2
```

Desired output;

```
Set 1
Set 2
```

Thank you please

Comment: I think you'll probably want to change your xml so that `set` is a property. `<cmdset name="Set 1">` b/c inner text is gonna pull everything inside `<cmdset></cmdset>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to select just the text content using the XPath `text()` function, for instance:

```
For Each textNode As XmlText In doc.SelectNodes("//cmdset/text()")
    Console.WriteLine(textNode.InnerText)
Next
```

Notice that I also changed the iterator from an `XmlElement` variable to an `XmlText` variable, since text content in an XML document is not considered to be element nodes, but rather text nodes.